# What is the risk that Windows 8's loopback protection feature protects me from?

Tags: network, windows

Windows 8 requires [Fiddler to set up an exemption](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configurefiddlerforwin8) when sending traffic to localhost.

Since this is a default setting (and affects many computers):

- What security benefit does this provide
- How can I list any exceptions that may be placed on my machine?  (By Fiddler or any other similar software)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fiddler is a proxy server that runs locally on your machine.  For this to work it needs to use the [loopback network interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback#Virtual_loopback_interface) (localhost).  In Windows 8 has a new runtime that allows for the running of [Immersive Apps](http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Windows-8-and-8-1-Knowledge-Base/What-are-Windows-8-s-Immersive-apps/ta-p/875577).  For all Immersive Apps, Win8+ runs them in an AppContainer.  All AppContainers are forbidden to use send network traffic to the localhost.  Fiddler falls into this category of applications, but it is obviously a necessity for it to use the localhost interface.

The exemption that you grant simply tells Win8+, "Hey, this application is cool, let it use the loopback interface to do its job."  And Windows says, "Fine!  But we don't like it."  There is no real security **benefit**, it's just what needs to happen for Fiddler to work.  Microsoft would probably argue that it's actually more insecure for you to allow Fiddler access to the localhost.

I just realized I didn't quite understand your question.  The loopback interface essentially sends packets to itself.  So the Windows kernel would pick them up and process them as best it can.  An exploited application might not have direct access to the operating system yet.  It could bind to the localhost, send a malicious packet through the interface and exploit the operating system this way.  [Here's an example](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/08/microsoft-security-sandbox-for-ie-still-broken-after-all-these-years/).

[This link explains more on Fiddler w/ Win8+](https://web.archive.org/web/20151204091513/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/fiddler/archive/2011/12/10/fiddler-windows-8-apps-enable-loopback-network-isolation-exemption.aspx)  
[Here's a program to manage your exemptions.](http://loopback.codeplex.com/)